# ImageMagik Crop and GhostScript PHP v 5.3.13 and Apache v 2.3.33

Tags: php, image-processing, ghostscript

I am trying to convert pdf file into jpeg image format using imagemagik crop and ghostscript.

I research a lot, but not getting any solution got so many links but my system compatiblity might be an issue.

> My System is Win 7
>
> PHP v 5.3.13
>
> Apache v 2.3.33
>
> wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-32b

I am not getting any proper link where i can find out dll file and make such changes in .dll file etc.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a JPEG then you can use Ghostscript directly to produce it. I can't see any reason why you would want to change a DLL, which realistically you can only do by changing and recompiling the source.

Eg:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812998/ghostscript-ps-to-jpg-output-without-white-space](http://This%20question%20seems%20relevant)

Comment: Sir My Question is related to installation of imagemagik and ghostscript with wamp and Windows 7.

Comment: And my answer tells you how to use Ghostscript. I know nothing about PHP so I can't tell you anything about that. I assume that you already know how to invoke ImageMagick, so you can simply use Ghostscript instead. If you don't then there are many answers on SO which contain methods for calling Ghostscript from PHP. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080032/ghostscript-not-working-in-php

Comment: OK Sir Please tell me how to install ghost in my current env which i specified above

Comment: You should probably say more explicitly what your problem is. However, if you go to www.ghostscript.com/downloads you will be able to download a Windows binary installer for Ghostscript. I'm going to assume that you haven't installed ImageMagick either, if you want to use that you will have to install it as well. Again You can download a Windows biary, eg http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php